# Invisible Elements Cause Blank Space

Tags: html, css

I have a hidden element which is hidden using

`visibility:hidden;`

but it still takes up space on the page where it would be if it was visible. This causes some other elements to be pushed down the page a bit further, and it looks strange. The reason it's hidden is because it will only show on mobile. Is there any way to remove this empty space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element with `visibility: hidden` still takes space in the page. Use `display: none` if you want to remove an element from the layout flow. **Although you can still interact with it in the DOM**, `display:none` will allow other elements to take up the space that would be allocated for it.

Also note that, **neither `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` respond to events**.

Comment: I'm using jQuery's slideToggle to hide and show it as well. Will this affect it?

Comment: Disregard that question. My issue had to do with both visibility as well as having some extra <br /> tags outside of the section I was hiding when they should've been inside.

Comment: I will answer anyway, for the sake of future visitors: jQuery `slideToggle` method actually works by setting `display:none` after the animation. So, no, the element wouldn't take space.

Answer (score 1):

without seeing your code...pretty hard to do...but default would be `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

```
visibility:hidden;
```

just makes the element hidden but does not remove it from the layout

use

```
display:none;
```

which removes it from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is because **`visibility: hidden;`** only hides the element and is equivalent to making it 100% transparent.

**`display: none;`** however, will hide your element like `visibility: hidden;`, but goes the extra step further and effectively removes it from your page (it doesn't *actually* remove it, it just gives that effect).